# Attoparsec Iteratee

Tags: haskell, loops, attoparsec

I wanted, just to learn a bit about Iteratees, reimplement a simple parser I made, using Data.Iteratee and Data.Attoparsec.Iteratee. I'm pretty much stumped though. Below I have a simple example that is able to parse *one* line from a file. My parser reads one line at a time, so I need a way of feeding lines to the iteratee until it's done. I've read all I've found googling this, but a lot of the material on iteratee/enumerators is pretty advanced. This is the part of the code that matters:

```
-- There are more imports above.
import Data.Attoparsec.Iteratee
import Data.Iteratee (joinI, run)
import Data.Iteratee.IO (defaultBufSize, enumFile)

line :: Parser ByteString -- left the implementation out (it doesn't check for 
                             new line)

iter = parserToIteratee line

main = do
    p <- liftM head getArgs
    i <- enumFile defaultBufSize p $ iter
    i' <- run i
    print i'
```

This example will parse and print one line from a file with multiple lines. The original script mapped the parser over a list of ByteStrings. So I would like to do the same thing here. I found `enumLines`in Iteratee, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use it. Maybe I misunderstand its purpose?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since your parser works on a line at a time, you don't even need to use attoparsec-iteratee.  I would write this as:

```
import Data.Iteratee as I
import Data.Iteratee.Char
import Data.Attoparsec as A

parser :: Parser ParseOutput
type POut = Either String ParseOutput

processLines :: Iteratee ByteString IO [POut]
processLines = joinI $ (enumLinesBS ><> I.mapStream (A.parseOnly parser)) stream2list
```

The key to understanding this is the "enumeratee", which is just the iteratee term for a stream converter.  It takes a stream processor (iteratee) of one stream type and converts it to work with another stream.  Both `enumLinesBS` and `mapStream` are enumeratees.

To map your parser over multiple lines, `mapStream` is sufficient:

```
i1 :: Iteratee [ByteString] IO (Iteratee [POut] IO [POut]
i1 = mapStream (A.parseOnly parser) stream2list
```

The nested iteratees just mean that this converts a stream of `[ByteString]` to a stream of `[POut]`, and when the final iteratee (stream2list) is run it returns that stream as `[POut]`.  So now you just need the iteratee equivalent of `lines` to create that stream of `[ByteString]`, which is what `enumLinesBS` does:

```
i2 :: Iteratee ByteString IO (Iteratee [ByteString] IO (Iteratee [POut] m [POut])))
i2 = enumLinesBS $ mapStream f stream2list
```

But this function is pretty unwieldy to use because of all the nesting.  What we really want is a way to pipe output directly between stream converters, and at the end simplify everything to a single iteratee.  To do this we use `joinI`, `(><>)`, and `(><>)`:

```
e1 :: Iteratee [POut] IO a -> Iteratee ByteString IO (Iteratee [POut] IO a)
e1 = enumLinesBS ><> mapStream (A.parseOnly parser)

i' :: Iteratee ByteString IO [POut]
i' = joinI $ e1 stream2list
```

which is equivalent to how I wrote it above, with `e1` inlined.

There's still important element remaining though.  This function simply returns the parse results in a list.  Typically you would want to do something else, such as combine the results with a fold.

edit: `Data.Iteratee.ListLike.mapM_` is often useful to create consumers.  At that point each element of the stream is a parse result, so if you want to print them you can use

```
consumeParse :: Iteratee [POut] IO ()
consumeParse = I.mapM_ (either (\e -> return ()) print)

processLines2 :: Iteratee ByteString IO ()
processLines2 = joinI $ (enumLinesBS ><> I.mapStream (A.parseOnly parser)) consumeParse
```

This will print just the successful parses.  You could easily report errors to STDERR, or handle them in other ways, as well.

Comment: Amazing answer, wish I could upvote it twice! Might I ask for an example of how to write that consumer? Let's say all I want to do is print the successful parse results, if that's a simple example.

Comment: @shintoist: I've added this now.